# Validating Polymer Paper Elements

Tags: javascript, validation, polymer

I'm building a polymer app that submits to a REST api and I've got all that up and running. But now I'm trying to add some simple validation to it and I can't figure out how to validate the paper-radio inputs. I just want to use HTML5 validation - but that may not be possible. The only thing is that I cannot use jQuery - its not an option for the project's parameters. Does anyone know how to validate the basic structure I'm using? (see below)

```
<paper-radio-group selected="{{selected}}">
  <paper-radio-button class="radio" value="{{value}}" name="{{name}}" label="{{label}}"></paper-radio-button>
  <paper-radio-button class="radio" value="{{value}}" name="{{name}}" label="{{label}}"></paper-radio-button>
  <paper-radio-button class="radio" value="{{value}}" name="{{name}}" label="{{label}}"></paper-radio-button>  
</paper-radio-group>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a recent article on 'Unit Testing Polymer Elements'

https://www.polymer-project.org/articles/unit-testing-elements.html

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I don't see anything in that article about validating polymer form elements.