# How does one validate paper-radio-group element with required attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, polymer

This is similar question as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27259897/validating-polymer-paper-elements) but it was not answered & is pre 1.0.
I need to ensure that at least one `paper-radio-button` is selected on form submit 
I can place a required attribute to each `paper-radio-button` but this means every radio-button have to be selected.

```
<iron-label> Type<br/>
    <paper-radio-group name="types" allow-empty-selection attr-for-selected="value" selected="{{model.type}}" noink >
        <paper-radio-button name="type" value="home" required> Home</paper-radio-button>
        <paper-radio-button name="type" value="work" required> Work</paper-radio-button>
        <paper-radio-button name="type" value="portal" required> Portal</paper-radio-button>
        <paper-radio-button name="type" value="shipping" required> Shipping</paper-radio-button>
        <paper-radio-button name="type" value="billing" required> Billing</paper-radio-button>
        <paper-radio-button name="type" value="other" required> Other</paper-radio-button>
    </paper-radio-group>
</iron-label>
```

Comment: Have you tried disabling `allowEmptySelection` and validating the `selected` value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of giving the user the option not selecting any radio button, it would be better to force a selection. You can do this by removing [`allow-empty-selection`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-radio-group#property-allowEmptySelection) from `paper-radio-group` and the `required` attribute from `paper-radio-button`. I also recommend using [`fallback-selection`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-radio-group#property-fallbackSelection) on `paper-radio-group` so that an unexpected value in `model.type` would result in a default value, such as "Other".

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.11.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-form/iron-form.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-label/iron-label.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-radio-group/paper-radio-group.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-radio-button/paper-radio-button.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-button/paper-button.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-form></x-form>

  <dom-module id="x-form">
    <template>
      <iron-form id="form">
        <form action="">
          <iron-label> Type<br/>
            <paper-radio-group name="types"  attr-for-selected="value" fallback-selection="other" selected="{{model.type}}" noink>
              <paper-radio-button name="type" value="home"> Home</paper-radio-button>
              <paper-radio-button name="type" value="work"> Work</paper-radio-button>
              <paper-radio-button name="type" value="portal"> Portal</paper-radio-button>
              <paper-radio-button name="type" value="shipping"> Shipping</paper-radio-button>
              <paper-radio-button name="type" value="billing"> Billing</paper-radio-button>
              <paper-radio-button name="type" value="other"> Other</paper-radio-button>
            </paper-radio-group>
          </iron-label>
          <div>
            <paper-button on-click="submit">Submit</paper-button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </iron-form>
    </template>
    <script>
      HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
        Polymer({
          is: 'x-form',
          properties : {
            model: {
              type: Object,
              value: function() { return {type: 'fake'}; }
            }
          },
          submit: function() {
            console.log('type', this.model.type);
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

<sup>[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/RRrNao?editors=1001)</sup>