# How to make paper-radio-group validation on Polymer 2.0

Tags: javascript, html, polymer-2.x

I'm trying to use `paper-radio-group` on Polymer 2.0. I discovered on this question ([How to enforce required paper-radio-group in Polymer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38003624/how-to-enforce-required-paper-radio-group-in-polymer)) that normal validation doesn't work because paper-radio-group doesn't implement `Polymer.IronFormElementBehavior`. So, one way to workaround is to create a new element that implements this behavior.

I did like the example of the other question:

```
<dom-module id="app-radio-group">
  <template>
    <style include="shared-styles">
       [invalid] ::slotted(paper-radio-button) {
        --paper-radio-button-label-color: red;
        --paper-radio-button-unchecked-color: red;
      }
    </style>
    <paper-radio-group
      id="group"
      attr-for-selected="{{attrForSelected}}"
      selected="{{selected}}">
      <div invalid$="[[!valid]]">
        <slot></slot>
      </div>
    </paper-radio-group>

  </template>

  <script>
    class AppRadioGroup extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'app-radio-group'; }

      static get behaviors() {
        return [
          'Polymer.IronFormElementBehavior'
        ];
      }

      get selectedItem() {
        return this.$.group.selectedItem;
      }

      validate() {
        this.valid = this.selectedItem != null;
        return this.valid;
      }
    }
    window.customElements.define(AppRadioGroup.is, AppRadioGroup);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

But, as the slot element creates a light dom (https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/shadow-dom#shadow-dom-and-composition) the actual `paper-radio-button` aren't really inside `paper-radio-group`. So, the effect of selecting just one radio button doesn't work and I can't get the result of the selected radio-button.

Any ideas how to make this paper-radio-group works with the iron-form validation?

Comment: If your form element is used with Polymer 2.0, it doesn't need to implement Polymer.IronFormElementBehavior as iron-form#2.0.0 won't rely on it. The events iron-form-element-register and iron-form-element-unregister are not fired on Polymer 2.0. https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-form-element-behavior

Answer (score 0):

As @HakanC show me that I don't need to implement ironformelementbehavior I ended up doing a manual validation.

Basically I use CSS to show the highlight the unanswered questions. I put a attribute `invalid` in the html element to check when is invalid or not and when I will validate the form I also call the functions the validate `paper-radio-group`s

CSS:

```
  paper-radio-group[invalid] paper-radio-button {
    --paper-radio-button-label-color: red;
    --paper-radio-button-unchecked-color: red;
  }
```

HTML:

```
      <div class="question-title">Question?</div>
      <paper-radio-group invalid$="[[_isRadioGroupInvalid(answer)]]" attr-for-selected="value" selected="{{answer}}">
        <paper-radio-button value="true">Yes</paper-radio-button>
        <paper-radio-button value="false">No</paper-radio-button>
      </paper-radio-group>
```

JS:

```
 _isRadioGroupInvalid(input) {
    if (input === undefined) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
  _validateRadioGroups() {
    for (let radioGroup of this.$.form.querySelectorAll('paper-radio-group')) {
      if (radioGroup.getAttribute('invalid') === '') {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

 _validateForm() {
    if (this.$.form.validate() === false && this._validateRadioGroups() === false) {
      //do case invalid form
    } else {
      //do case valid form
    }
  }
```