# Validation on polymer paper-radio-group

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I am dynamically generating *paper-radio-group* along with other paper elements on my page such as *paper-input*, paper-dropdown-menu.
I need to `validate` that only one of the *paper-radio-button* is selected from the `group`.

1. I found that there is no required `attribute` or `validate()` `function` on *paper-radio-group* which can be `called` upon to `validate` it, however, we have `validate()` `function` on *paper-radio-button* which just check whether the `radio-button` is selected or it shows the `error` `message`.
2. I found that there is an `attribute` *allow-empty-selection*, however, I need to `validate` on a next `button`. For other paper elements, for example, *paper-input*, I call `validate()` on next `button` and it displays the `error` `message`, but lack of `validate` method in *paper-radio-group*.

Is there a reason for not having validate on *radio-group*, which I am missing.

Has someone done it earlier or help me on it.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/37714472/6277151 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/38003624/6277151

Comment: Thank tony, the second link was helpful. However, i am not sure why there is no validate  method on radio-group, and I guess my requirement is basic requirement of radio button.

Comment: There's no validate on `paper-radio-group` because it doesn't implement `IronFormElementBehavior` out of the box (and perhaps it should), but for now, you'll have to implement it yourself as detailed in the second link.